# viewports that differentiate between ipads and iphones

Tags: html, mobile

I have a fixed-width site that becomes responsive below 660px width via media queries. However, I want iPad users to see the full, fixed-width site at 1024px, not a cropped version at 768px. When I add the `viewport` meta tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

The site is responsive for the iPhone, but the iPad user's site is cropped at 768px. If I remove the meta tag, the iPad user views the site like a desktop user, but so does the iPhone.  What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, it's a simple error in your markup. You're using a `-` where you should be using `=` to assign the value "device-width".

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```